# C# Winforms Enable/Disable button based on function

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a button on my winform to be enabled or disabled based on the return value of a particular function.  Basically, I'm trying the following code in various places where the function will possible return a different value:

```
btnNewNotices.Enabled = isSelectedPrinterValid();
this.btnNewNotices.Refresh()
```

However, this is not working.  Why is it when I call the refresh method after the enabled property is changed, that the button does not become enabled?  I have to close the form and reopen it before the button properly disables.  What is the best way to accomplish what I need here without having to bounce the form?

Comment: Why are you calling `Refresh()` ?

Comment: Could you include some more context? How and where are you executing the above?

Comment: Did you check what values your `isSelectedPrinterValid()` returns? This code should work as long as the above method returns values you expect. And yes, you don't need `Refresh()`.

Comment: `Refresh()` causes the button to repaint itself, and resets the `Enabled` property. Why are you using it?

Comment: `"I have to close the form and reopen it"` - Are you creating a new instance of the form when you do that?  This doesn't make sense.  Setting the `Enabled` property, well, sets the `Enabled` property.  You definitely shouldn't be calling `Refresh()`, nor should you need to do anything else.

Comment: I don't really get the down vote on this.  You can't say that it isn't a useful, question and there's no indication of a "lack of research."  It's a reasonable question, and doing a google search on this topic does not really reveal a clear answer on the specific situation.  Most hits are for webforms which does not apply to this situation.

Comment: @KobyDouek My expectation was that refresh() redraws the control based on the new state of the control's properties as it did in previous generations of MSFT Visual languages - not that it would have any such side effects as you suggest.  MSFT documentation states that the refresh method "Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls."  This does not indicate that a control's properties would be affected, although it's not obvious to me what "invalidates its client area" means.  Thanks very much for your answer below, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, but it's pretty straight forward.

Using `.Refresh();` causes the button to repaint itself, and resets the `Enabled` property. There's no reason to use it in your context. Just remove it.

```
btnNewNotices.Enabled = isSelectedPrinterValid();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add a `Databinding` for the `Enabled` property.
if your method is implemented in your `Form` then you can define a `Property`

```
public bool IsSelectedPrinterValid
{
    get{ return this.isSelectedPrinterValid(); }
}
```

And add a Databinding as following:

```
btnNewNotices.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", this, "IsSelectedPrinterValid");
```

You can refresh your value:

```
btnNewNotices.DataBindings[0].ReadValue();
```

The common way is to implement a ViewModel containing all Properties and Methods you need and bind your controls to these.